# Overriding >> and polymorphism

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So I am trying to do something, but I am not sure it can/should be done this way in c++.

I have a file of objects I want to read in.  Each object is of one of 3 types of classes which are part of a hierarchy

In the file I have a discriminator to tell me which is which.

Lets say the  classes are:

Checking, Savings and are subclasses of Account.

Can i build code such that:

Account a;

istream >> a;

Will let me polmorphically set the resulting data in a to the appropriate type ?
( i realize the code would have to be there to do it)

Hope that makes sense.  Or, do i just need a "deserialize" method or something that i don't use operator overloading for?

I can't use any existing non STL libraries out there, as this is for a classroom example.

Thanks!

Edit:  I think my question may have been unclear:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Transactions& transactions)
{
```

is my function, and i want to have transaction set to a subclass of Transaction....

I'm thinking this isn't possible without some of the new newer features
some have mentioned?

Comment: I think conceptually you are thinking in a wrong way. If you take `Account` and try to `cin >> a`, I believe you can not distinguish conceptually which account you are trying to deserialize. Is it a checking or a saving account?

So probably, you want to take a concrete account class (like Saving), and then you can do cin >> s; because then you know what you are trying to deserialize. And of course, then you can overload the operator easily.

Comment: No.   Given `a` being an `Account`, `some_istream >> a` is not polymorphic.   The type of `a` is fixed, and is not magically changed by an I/O operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. Quoting from your question, if you have a declaration:

```
Account a;
```

Then that's what `a` is. In C++, the types of all objects must be known at compile time. This is fundamental to C++, there are no exceptions or workarounds. The type of `a` cannot be changed at runtime, based on some arbitrary criteria.

> Will let me polmorphically set the resulting data in a to the
> appropriate type ?

Nope. `a` is an `Account`. This is immutable, and cannot be changed based on runtime conditions.

> Or, do i just need a "deserialize" method

That would be a very common approach, and was pretty much the rule of the land before C++17.

In C++17 you could declare an

```
std::variant<std::monostate, Checking, Savings> a;
```

And then define an implement a `>>` for this, which will replace the default-constructed `a` monostate with an instance of one or the other class.

Note that the type of the object `a` is still fixed, and no rules are broken: `a` is a variant type. It has a specific type that's defined at compile-time.

Comment: I think my question is misleading...

Comment: But the answer will still be the same: C++ does not work this way. If you have a reference to an object, whether it's passed to an `>>` overload or any other function, the dereferenced object can only be set to the same object. It cannot be set to a different object, such as a subclass. This is fundamental to C++. You're thinking of the way objects work in Java or C#. C++ is not Java or C#.

Comment: You are exactly right.  I haven't done much coding in C++ in the last 15 years, mostly C# and it has impacted my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want polymorphism you need pointers or references.  Objects are always the type you declare them as.  Nothing more, nothing less.

So you need a separate factory function that can decide which type to create at runtime.  For example, it could look something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Account> read_account(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string type = read_type(is);
    if (type == "checking") {
        auto acct = std::make_unique<Checking>();
        is >> *acct;
        return acct;
    } else {
        auto acct = std::make_unique<Savings>();
        is >> *acct;
        return acct;
    }
    return {};  // or throw
}
```